# how to create a folder using http REST msgraph api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create a folder on onedrive using msgraph api. I'm posting to "/drive/root" with the following json body

```
{"name":"hello","folder": {  "childCount": 0  }, }
```

Here is the error I get. What am I doing wrong?

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "The parameter name does not exist in method GetById.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "12186368-8f5e-4e7a-81d3-09f3401fda17",
      "date": "2016-02-23T15:44:54"
    }
  }
}
, 400, Bad Request]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please POST to the `children` collection of the parent folder - e.g. POST "/drive/root/children" or POST "/me/drive/root/children".

Comment: thank you @MarekRycharski for your response. Now I get the following. I know my access token is valid because I can call other APIs with it like getting list of files etc....  <br/> [{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "362c0cf7-c73a-4413-b9c0-b3d74bd6d290",
      "date": "2016-02-23T19:56:50"
    }
  }
}
, 401, Unauthorized]

Comment: Your token had Files.Read scope, which is sufficient for read operations, but for writes you need Files.ReadWrite. Please configure that delegated permission for your application.

Comment: thanks @MarekRycharski  strange because when I registered my app I gave it Files.readwrite. BTW this is a trial account could that be the reason?

Comment: here is my permissions list  <br/>•Sign you in and read your profile
•Have full access to your files and files shared with you
•Read your files and files shared with you
•Have full access of your contacts 
•Read your contacts 
•Have full access to your calendars 
•Read your calendars 
•Send mail as you 
•Read and write access to your mail 
•Read your mail 
•Read and write all groups
•Read all groups
•Read and write all users' full profiles
•Read all users' full profiles
•Sign you in and read your profile

Comment: If you added the added the Files.ReadWrite permission to your app after it was consented you need to re-consent. Please remove its access for the tenant you're using and request a new token to re-consent.

Comment: thank you. Actually I re registered the app (with the same permissions) and it started working. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution that helped me, hopes this works for you too:
(post method)

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/drive/items/root:/${ChannelName}:/children`

creates it at the root folder, don't forget the ":". Took me 3 days, went inside the wall :/